# Frequency of maintenance windows in Android Doze Mode

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there any documentation on how frequent are doze mode maintenance windows in Android? I have read different things but nothing official. Someone said its 1, 2, 4, 6 hrs and then maintenance window re-occurs every 6 hours but could not find it anywhere in android documentation.

Comment: That's about what I have been seeing in practice. AFAIK, it's not documented, and probably intentionally not documented, to give them wiggle room.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that we can do assumption only about duration of maintenance windows, rather than about frequency. [As docs say](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby), it's unstable value:

> Over time, the system schedules maintenance windows less and less
>   frequently, helping to reduce battery consumption in cases of
>   longer-term inactivity when the device is not connected to a charger.

And what about duration of maintenance windows, it seems that they should be equal 10 minutes for jobs and network connectivity, and 10 seconds for alarms. [From docs:](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details)

> ** If jobs restrictions are in force, the app is granted a window of ten minutes at the specified interval. At the end of the ten minutes,
>   all jobs are postponed until the next window.
>
> † If alarm restrictions are in force, all alarms will fire at the
>   scheduled window, and run for a maximum of 10 seconds.
>
> ‡ If network access is restricted, the app is granted a window of 10
>   minutes to use the network at the specified interval.

*P.S.* There are also Doze-on-the-go, or Light Doze, since Android Nougat, and in that new mode the maintenance windows are more frequent than what we saw with Deep Doze (on plain Doze mode). 
*P.P.S.* It's possible also that OEMs are free to tweak the different timeout values.